# Green currents in Arakelov theory

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory, arakelov-theory

Let $K$ be number field and $\mathcal{O}_K$ its ring of integers. In Arakelov theory the idea is to enrich an arithmetic scheme $X$ over $\mathcal{O}_K$ "at infinity", that is to add data at the archemedian places. Now in higher dimensions, an Arakelov divisor of $X$ is given by the datum of a cycle of $X$ and the added data of a Green current $g_D$ (or rather one for each archemedian place of $K$).

My understanding of why currents show up is roughly this: if $M$ is a manifold, and $C,D$ closed submanifolds of complementary dimension, then
$$C\cdot D=\int_C \delta_D$$
where $\delta_D$ is the "integrations along D"-current. Or rather this is true **if** $\delta_D$ were smooth along $C$. This doesn't have to be true, and so we would like to change $\delta_D$. What sort of class is smooth, well for instance the elements $A^{p-1,p-1}(X)\subset D^{p-1,p-1}(X)$. So we change $\delta_D$, namely we add $dd^{\mathrm{c}} g$  for all well-choose $g$ such that
$$dd^{\mathrm{c}}g+\delta_D\in A^{p-1,p-1}(X),$$
and in particular smooth.

The existence of such Green currents can therefore, if I understand correctly, be understood as some sort of "analytic moving lemma". My problem now is that it seems that the "smoothing out"-data of a Green current seems very auxiliary, similar to a principal divisor in algebraic geometry used to have cycles meet transversely.

I'm aware that this isn't the case, and I'm sure there is a good reason why, I'm just not aware of it. So
**why isn't a Green current auxiliary data?**

Comment: Isn’t it kind of auxiliary? At least rationally arithmetic Chow = arithmetic K-theory and in the latter there are no Green currents.

Comment: @crystalline I mean auxilary in the sense that if I have two different Green currents $g,g'$ for a divisor $D$, the corresponding Arakelov divisors $[D,g],[D,g']$ don't have to agree, so somehow more then "smoothing out" is happening.

Answer (score 2):

If you say that the choice of a principal divisor for moving into transversal position is "auxiliary", and you're asking for the "non-auxiliary part" of the data of a Green current, you may divide out rational equivalences for the question. As the arithmetic Chow group of arithmetic divisor classes is isomorphic to hermitian line bundles, the question transforms to: Why is a metric on a line bundle no auxiliary data? But in many cases a metric follows from the application. For example dynamical systems induce metrics on the polarizing line bundle. Thus, the metric contains data of the application, e.g. of a dynamical system.